# codeigniter set message and inserting time error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 2 problems to solve. First I have this small function

```
if(!$verified) {
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
            $this->form_validation->set_message('token_expired', 'Token expired try again.');
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('forgot_password_view');
            $this->load->view('footer');
            }
```

I only pasted the code which was necessary so when verified fails, I want to load the set message on the forgetpasswordview but the problem is I am using that page for validation errors with other things and I also want this message to show if this function doesnt work. Here is the view.

```
<div class="well">
        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
        <?php 
        if(validation_errors() != false) 
        { 
            echo '<div class="form-group alert alert-danger has-error">';
                echo'<ul>';
                    echo validation_errors('<li class="control-label">', '</li>');
                echo'</ul>';
            echo '</div>';   
        }

        ?>
        <?php echo form_open('login/reset_password'); ?>
        <h1>Forgot your password?</h1>
        <p>Please enter your email address so we will send you a link to change your password</p>
        <div class="<?php if(form_error('email')!= null){echo ' has-error';} ?>">
        <input  name="email" style="width: 20%" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email Address"/>
        <button style="margin-top:20px;" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I thought that the first echo validation_errors might take care of the token_expired but ofcourse doesnt work, and the second validation works when I check if the email is undergoes validation.

My second problem is that, I have a function which works but inserting current time + 15 minutes. I am in helsinki/Finland so I use it like this.

```
 function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Helsinki');
```

......and in the function its

```
$data = array(
         'expiration' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime("+15 minutes")),
         );
```

But the problem with that is it works fine till 12PM but when its 1pm it should dis play 13:15:00 but it shows 01:15:00 So need to fix that problem as well.

Comment: `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+15 minutes")),`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks for the answer :D , can you help me with the other problem ?

Comment: Mark my below answer and bring it on.. :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar the other question is written on the post as well, the validation error, please help me on the other one so I can mark both answers :)

Comment: check now..  Added some code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not set form validation message without submitting form intead pass a variable to your view

```
if(!$verified) 
{
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
    $message['token_expired']= 'Token expired try again.';//(token_expired)?'Token expired try again.':'';
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('forgot_password_view', $message);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

And in view

```
if(isset($token_expired) && $token_expired != '') 
{  
    echo $token_expired;
}
```

For your second problem

```
$data = array(
             'expiration' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+15 minutes")),
             );
```

Comment: I got what you mean, but the problem is , that view is being used, normally as a page for people who forgot password, and I want to throw people back to the same page if the function running returns false, so basically now if I go to that page, it will show Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: token_expired

Filename: views/forgot_password_view.php

Line Number: 4